# Adding all table fields into the SE11 structure?

Tags: sap-data-dictionary

I'm learning SAP and ABAP language, I need to create a structure with all the fields of the SFLIGHT database table and a few more. Do I have to enter all the fields of the SFLIGHT table manually or is there any possibility to add all the fields of a given table at once?

I have to create DDIC structure like that:
[image: Ready structure screen]

Do I have to fill this component names manually?
[image: My screen]

Comment: In what you show, `ZFLIGHT_S_ALV` already contains all columns of `SPFLI` table (via `.INCLUDE`). So your question is also the answer.

Comment: Are you asking about creating the structure type in the dictionary or about declaring a structure type/variable in your program?

Comment: @Philipp About declaring all datatable components in new structure. Something like  Suncatcher's answer :)

Comment: @SandraRossi Now i know :) I was confused by the example in the tutorial, where .INCLUDE was declared, plus all the components. Now I know that all we need to do is write .INCLUDE and we will have all the components of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code solution is given by Jonas, but if you are asking about SE11-way then

**Edit** => scroll down to **Include** => click on **Insert**

[image]

https://techazmaan.com/ddic-include-structure/

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what i meant :)

Answer (score 0):

With the [`TYPES ... LINE OF`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-us/abaptypes_referring.htm) statement one can declare a type which represents a structure for one line of a table:

```
TYPES flight TYPE LINE OF sflight.

" the structure type can then be used in the program
DATA(scheduled_flight) = VALUE flight(
  " ...
).
INSERT scheduled_flight INTO sflight.
```

Thus usually there is no need to declare such a structure in the dictionary, as it already exists implicitly through the table creation.